# Pulling a file from excel and then removing duplicates

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to remove duplicates from string and the result need to look like this:
CNG41383874
CNG41383875
CNG41383876
Tried to convert into dictionary but got data in characters form instead. Any ideas how this can be solved?

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.concat(pd.read_excel('Todays sheet.xlsx', sheet_name=None), ignore_index=True)

cr = pd.DataFrame(data,columns= ['Carrier'])
rf = pd.DataFrame(data,columns= ['Ref/Lic Nr'])
#Locks data from column 
amtg = data.loc[data.Carrier=='AMTG', 'Ref/Lic Nr']
bgxp = data.loc[data.Carrier=='BGXP', 'Ref/Lic Nr']
dtcv = data.loc[data.Carrier=='DTCV', 'Ref/Lic Nr']
ceeg = data.loc[data.Carrier=='CEEG', 'Ref/Lic Nr']
echs = data.loc[data.Carrier=='ECHS', 'Ref/Lic Nr']
#prints list without index
 
amtg1=(amtg.to_string(index=False, header=False))
bgxp1=(bgxp.to_string(index=False, header=False))
dtcv1=(dtcv.to_string(index=False, header=False))
ceeg1=(ceeg.to_string(index=False, header=False))
echs1=(echs.to_string(index=False, header=False))

amtg2 = list(dict.fromkeys(amtg1))
print(amtg2)
```

**Result**  [' ', 'C', 'N', 'G', '4', '1', '3', '8', '7', '\n', '5', '6', 'S', 'E', 'U', 'A', 'L', 'M', '9', '2', '0', 'B', 'D', 'F', 'T', 'K', 'O', 'H', 's']
[imput sheet format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hUve.png)

Comment: Can you add screenshot of your input format?

Comment: added mate , thx

Comment: If you want to delete the duplicates from dataframes like "amtg", "bgxp" using particular column, you can use drop duplicates function. " amtg.drop_duplicates(['Ref/Lic Nr'], keep = "last", inplace = True) "

Comment: thank you mate , yeah saw taht few seconds before)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that what may be happening is you are forgetting to make a list. Try this:

```
lst = [amtg1, bgxp1, dtcv1, ceeg1, echs1]
amtg2 = list(dict.fromkeys(amtg1))
print(atmg2)
```

Another way to produce a list with no duplicates:

```
amtg2 = list(set(amtg1)))
```

Comment: Still get the same ,only  separate latter

Answer (score 0):

Found how to solve

added at the beggings
`data1 = data.drop_duplicates(subset=["Ref/Lic Nr"], keep="first")`